# Remove item from array in VueJS child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm learning VueJS so this example may appear contrived but bear with me. I'm learning how components work.

The issue is I can't get the Delete button in each row to delete the appropriate item from the array (I'm using splice). Instead, it always removes the first item from the array. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <p>Tasks: {{ count }}</p>
    <input v-model="task">
    <button v-on:click="addItem">Add Item</button>
    <button v-on:click="clearAll">Clear All</button>

    <ul>
        <todo-item
            v-for="(item, index) in todos"
            v-bind:todo="item"
            v-bind:key="item.id"
            v-on:delete-item="deleteItem"
        ></todo-item>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the JS file:

```
const tasks = [
  { id: 0, text: 'Clean the house' },
  { id: 1, text: 'Order groceries' },
  { id: 2, text: 'Build an app' }
];

Vue.component('todo-item', {
  props: ['todo'],
  methods: {
  },
  template: `
    <li>
      {{ todo.text }} 
      <button type="button" v-on:click="$emit('delete-item')">Delete</button>
    </li>
  `
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    task: '',
    todos: tasks
  },
  computed: {
    count() {
      return this.todos.length;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addItem () {
      if (this.task) {
        this.todos.push({ id: this.todos.length, text: this.task });
        this.task = '';
        this.count++;
      }
    },

    deleteItem (index) {
      this.todos.splice(index, 1);
      this.count--;
    },

    clearAll() {
      this.todos = [];
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You aren't passing the `index` to `deleteItem`. `v-on:delete-item="deleteItem(index)"`

Comment: Perfect. That was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are firing the `delete-item` event but you are never giving your parent component any information which todo-item should be deleted.

My suggestion is to pass the item-id in the event by doing 
`<button type="button" v-on:click="$emit('delete-item', todo.id)">Delete</button>`

The id will then be passed into the `deleteItem` method as the parameter. Alternatively you can pass the index to the item-component as a prop and use the index instead of the id to identify the item you need to delete (like what you're trying to do now).